# Determine a basis for the subspace of $\,\Bbb p^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=\{a+bx+cx^2+dx^3 \in P_3\mid a+b=c\}$.
How to determine a basis for the subspace of $\,\Bbb p^3$ ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @copper.hat +1, Putting a question mark behind a sentence does not make it a question.

Comment: I wonder how well would you two copper.hat and Arthur would fare writing in Mandarin, Korean, Japanese, Russian, ...

Comment: @ABC: The question, as it was originally stated, was not clear to me, hence my question. It had nothing to do with language as you seem to have presumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of bases in linear algebra is that they allow you to work with coordinates and forget about the actual nature of the vectors.

You know a basis of $p^3$. One example could be $1,x,x^2,x^3$. Then, every polynomial in $p^3$ can be identified by its coordinates in this basis. So, the polynomial $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ is represented by $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$.

Now, you have a subspace that is defined by $a+b=c$, i.e. $a+b-c=0$. In coordinates we are just finding the space of $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $a+b-c=0$. This is a system that is already written in echelon form. We can take $a$ as a pivot, $b$, $c$, and $d$ as free variables. Then we can build a basis of the space of solutions of this equation $a+b-c=0$, by giving the free variables, values $0$ to all and $1$ to one of them.

So, we put $b=1$, $c=0$, and $d=0$ and get $a=-1$. This gives the vector of coordinates $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Then we put $b=0$, $c=1$, and $d=0$, and get $a=1$. This is the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Finally we put $b=0$, $c=0$, and $d=1$, and get $a=0$. This gives the vector of coordinates $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Now we can *translate* coordinates into actual vectors of your space. The coordinate vectors obtained correspond to the polynomials $-1+x$, $1+x^2$, and $x^3$, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar way:

Note that $A=\{ x \mapsto a + bx + (a+b)x^2+d x^3 \}_{a,b,d}$. Choose $(a,b,d)$ from $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ to get $g_1(x) = 1+x^2, g_2(x)=x+x^2, g_3(x) = x^3$.

It should be clear that $A = \operatorname{sp} \{g_1,g_2,g_3\}$, it remains to check that the $g_k$ are linearly independent.

Suppose $\phi = \alpha_1 g_1+ \alpha_2 g_2+\alpha_3 g_3 = 0$. We have $\phi(0) = \alpha_1$, so $\alpha_1 = 0$. Since $\phi'(0) = \alpha_2$, we have $\alpha_2 = 0$, and since $\phi(1) = \alpha_3$, we have $\alpha_3=0$, hence the $g_k$ are linearly independent.

Note that there is nothing 'special' about the vectors $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ other than that they form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or whatever field you are using).